# Retrieve form data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I created checkboxes with form for filter data from my model.
JavaScript code add textbox when checkbox is enabled.
My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve data from textbox and filter by view my template.

Example of my code:

Views.py

```
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()
    form_data = request.GET.copy()
    name = form_data.get("nameinput")
    year = form_data.get("yearinput")
    print(year)
    print(name)
    if form.is_valid():
        if '1' in form.cleaned_data['choice_1']:
            data = data.filter(naslov=form.cleaned_data['nameinput'])
        if '2' in form.cleaned_data['choice_0']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=form.cleaned_data['yearinput'])
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    filter = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('year', 'Year'), ('name', 'Name')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': 'choice', 'class': 'myclass'}))
```

models.py

```
class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)   
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor) + ', ' + str(self.videofile)
```

filtar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
<title></title>

<style>
input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 15px;
    background:#ccc;
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:block;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:block;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.naslov}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datumObjave}}</td>
        <td>{{x.autor}}</td>
    </tr>   
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<br>
<form action="{% url 'filtar' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.myclass').click(function(){
      $(this).prop('checked') ?
      $('form').append(`<input id="${$(this).val()}input" style="display:block;margin:5px" placeholder="${$(this).val()} details"></input>`) :
      $(`form #${$(this).val()}input`).remove();
    });
</script>
</body> 
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Image:

[image]

My problem is that filters don't work at all, page just refresh and keep showing all data.
I know something is wrong with my view but I don't know how to fix it.
I think problem might be that I am using wrong names of textfields or checkboxes but all I tried not helped, it's always same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I follow your Javascript, but if it's appending another field to the form called something other than "filter", Django is going to ignore it.

Also just noticed that your form has POST specified as its method, but you are passing `request.GET` to the form in `filtar`

One possibility is to skip Django forms altogether and look in  `request.POST` for whatever you appended. You don't need to be so paranoid about validation if it's just a search string. Another possibility  to add hidden fields to your form, and use your Javascript to fill them in. A third is to not write this code yourself, and just use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: My variables (dynamic textbox created when checkbox is enabled) are named "nameinput" and "yearinput" But when I am trying to fetch data in views.py with "form_data = request.GET.copy()", "name = form_data.get("nameinput")", "year = form_data.get("yearinput")" I am getting nothing. Do you maybe have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve form data do this

```
form_data = request.GET.copy()
```

Then to access the data in each field, use their name

```
year = form_data.get("Year")
name = form_data.get("Name")
```

Comment: I tried to put it at my view.py but problem is still the same, nothing changes, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: try using javascript (document.getElementById) to pick the values, arrange them as json (JSON.stringify) then pass it to your server, then use python (json.loads) to deserialize it